# Using elasticsearch.js queries in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch

I'm trying to use elasticsearch.js queries in my AngularJS controller, but haven't been able to pass them as params in an http request, or use them in the elasticsearch search() method. What is the recommended syntax?

```
import elasticsearch from "elasticsearch";

export default class SearchDirectiveController {
  constructor($scope, $http, SearchDirectiveService) {
    this.es = new elasticsearch.Client({
      host: 'http://192.168.99.100:9200',
      log: 'trace'
    });

    this.search = () => {
      this.es.search({
        index: 'voter',
        "query": {
            "match": {
              "first": "roger"
            }
          }
        }
      }).then((resp) => {
          var hits = resp.hits.hits;
          this.users = hits;
          $scope.$digest();
      },(err) => {
          console.trace(err.message);
      });
    }

    this.fullTextSearch = () => {
      $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: 'http://192.168.99.100:9200/voter/voter,address/_search'
      }).then(function successCallback(resp) {
          console.log(resp.data.hits.hits);
          let hits = resp.data.hits.hits;
          $scope.users = hits;
      }, function errorCallback(err) {
          console.trace(err.message);
      }, {
        params: {
          "query": {
              "match": {
                "first": "roger"
              }
            }
          }
        });
      }
  }

}

SearchDirectiveController.$inject = ['$scope', '$http', 'SearchDirectiveService'];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was that I forgot the key "body" on the search object:

```
    this.searchQuery = (field) => {
      return {
        'query': {
          'wildcard': {
            '_all': '*' + this.all + '*'
          }
        }
      };
    };

    this.search = (field) => {
      this.es.search({
        index: 'voter',
        body:  this.searchQuery(field)
      }).then((resp) => {
        const hits = resp.hits.hits;
        this.users = hits;
        $scope.$digest();
      }, (err) => {
        console.trace(err.message);
      });
    };
  }
```